# NPM has stopped working on Windows 7 64bit, hangs on install/update

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

At some point my version of NPM stopped working.  It seems to have happened when I tried to update npm (from 1.4 shipping with node to a modern 2.x version) a few weeks ago and has steadily gotten worse.  I had to change the Environment variable to point to my npm directory before my node directory (to pick up the new version of npm), at that point everything just stopped working.  I switched the environment variable back, and then updates would just hang.  But strangely when I tried to debug it and add a --verbose to the command the update would work most of the time.  Sometimes they hung on the

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/PACKAGE_NAME
```

but most of the time they worked.  This now happens with the old version of NPM (1.4.1) and the new version that I installed (2.1.17), everything always fails on a GET command (usually but not always the first one).   I have hit cache-clear, I have wiped out the temp directory,  I have tried wiping out %APPDATA/roaming/npm/, and reinstalling everything.  I have no proxy in place, but I have run:

```
 npm config set proxy
```

to set the proxy to blank.  I have set the registry to http (rather than https) and set strict-ssl to false.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs, to no luck.  I have tried running the commands from an admin cmd prompt rather than a normal command prompt all to no avail.  I've run out of ideas, and really need NPM to work...

Below is the output of trying to install grunt-cli after clearing out the %APPDATA/roaming/npm directory:

```
C:\Users\Kris Erickson>npm install -g grunt-cli --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'grunt-cli',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@1.4.28
npm info using node@v0.10.35
npm verb node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
npm verb cache add [ 'grunt-cli', null ]
npm verb cache add name=undefined spec="grunt-cli" args=["grunt-cli",null]
npm verb parsed url { protocol: null,
npm verb parsed url   slashes: null,
npm verb parsed url   auth: null,
npm verb parsed url   host: null,
npm verb parsed url   port: null,
npm verb parsed url   hostname: null,
npm verb parsed url   hash: null,
npm verb parsed url   search: null,
npm verb parsed url   query: null,
npm verb parsed url   pathname: 'grunt-cli',
npm verb parsed url   path: 'grunt-cli',
npm verb parsed url   href: 'grunt-cli' }
npm verb lock grunt-cli C:\Users\Kris Erickson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\671ef8ac-grunt-cli.lock
npm verb addNamed [ 'grunt-cli', '' ]
npm verb addNamed [ null, '*' ]
npm verb lock grunt-cli@ C:\Users\Kris Erickson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\d63f3d0b-grunt-cli.lock
npm verb request where is /grunt-cli
npm verb request registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm verb request id dc44ca4b260df8c3
npm verb url raw /grunt-cli
npm verb url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './grunt-cli' ]
npm verb url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm verb request where is https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 13:36:28
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
/
```

Note: the spinner never stops (at least I have left it 10 minutes and nothing happened).

Comment: FWIW you can disable the spinner and re-enable output by doing `npm config set spin false` and `npm config set loglevel http`. I always do this after installing node nowadays because it can help with problems like this and you can tell if something is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have installed a new `npm` but it is not actually being used (or did you revert back to 1.4.28?)

In either case, try following the directions here https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows for updating to the latest `npm` on Windows.  Latest is currently 2.4.1.  I recommend using Option 3.

Then try running your `npm install` command with maximum verbosity:

`npm -ddd install -g grunt-cli`

and upload your logfile as a gist https://gist.github.com either here or as a new issue at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues, and we'll help you get this sorted out.

Comment: I did install and switch to the new NPM and then switched back (by changing environment variables).  I do have both git and cygwin installed and have found this causes issues with a lot of unix tools ported to windows especially those dealing with SSH (Vagrant for example thinks the box is a unix variant and not running GIT bash or cygwin bash because of conflicting environment variables). But I will take your suggestion and post to github issues.

Answer (score 0):

The version number you're using doesn't comply with the [semantic versionning](http://semver.org/) convention `npm` uses: you need to specify a `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH` version number.

You can either:

1. Use the `0.2.x` notation to specify that you don't care what patch version you use, as long as the major.minor matches
2. Use the `~0.2.0` notation to specify that you don't care what patch version you use, as long as the major.minor matches
3. Read [npm's documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies) and [semver's documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html) for other possibilities...

Hope This helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am running node in windows 8.1. This issue popped up on a new machine build and I searched for hours for a resolution with no success. Finally. in desperation I used fiddler in an attempt to see what calls were being made by npm AND magically the problems went away.

On further investigation I found that npm appears to require two windows environment variables to be set:

Try the following in a command prompt before running npm (Note: if you are actually behind a proxy then replace the empty quotes with your proxy address):

```
Setx http_proxy ""
Setx https_proxy ""
```